# Error during installation of resigned watch os app

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to resign ios app with watch app.
As usual, I delete `_CodeSignature` folder, run `codesign` with provisioning, certificate, and entitlements.
It completes without error which is expected. Bud during installation from Xcode I receive the following errors:

```
Executable stub at ... watch.app/_WatchKitStub/WK not signed by Apple
The WatchKit 2.0 app being installed contains an invalid application executable.
```

Near the `_CodeSignature` folder there is `_WatchKitStub` with the only file `WK` there.
What is the purpose of this file? Should I also resign it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple expects (in part) the following structure:

```
MainApp.app
|
+- Watch/
   |
   +- MainAppWatchApp.app/
      |
      +- MainAppWatchApp (WatchKit stub executable -- re-signed)
      +- _WatchKitStub/
         |
         +- WK (WatchKit stub executable -- unmodified)
```

So `WK` shouldn't be resigned even if it's mach-O binary.

Comment: Hey @Alexei are you able to run the watchOS app after resigned? How did you connect to the watchOS device through the command line?

Comment: Hi @Nik. You just need to install the app on your iPhone with a connected watch. This could be done via xcode. That should work

Comment: Is there a way if we could launch the app on the watch device through the terminal or through the ios host app?

Comment: @Nik good question, but I don't think I have the answer for it.